# Loading SWF doesn't work when SWF is stored on local PC

Tags: flash, security, xul, xulrunner, browser-security

I have an HTML file which contains a Flash .FLV player; which then loads a given FLV video and plays it. The idea is all these files are stored locally on the PC as part of an application install, we use HTML/flash for the help/manual.

On my PC it works fine but on a user's PC nothing is displayed. However if I host the exact same file-structure online and give them the URL, it works perfectly.

I am guessing this is a security issue of some sort but have no idea how to address it. The browser being used is actually a XULRunner app, i.e it's the FireFox 3 engine but not actually FF. Since my PC isa  developer PC it's entirely possible I've done something in the past on another project that makes it work, rather than my PC being special in some way.

For reference the HTML has the following in it - this is generated from some 3rd-party app:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="723" height="445" id="FLVPlayer">
  <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
  <param name="salign" value="lt" />
  <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Halo_Skin_2&amp;streamName=../../videos&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" width="723" height="445">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Halo_Skin_2&amp;streamName=../../videos&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sure is a security issue browsers do not have access to local files.
It worked on your system because you were in your sandbox.
Two things you can do.
First one  - Host the FLVs online and access it that way. Like every other player out there.
Second one - Create an Air app.

Comment: Can you explain the sandbox... I'm sure one can add exceptions but I don't know how. It is not an option to have the files online as the app must work offline, and it is an embedded HTML widget so I don't think AIR is appropriate.

Comment: A sandbox is the working environment the swf is running in generally domain based. In the development sandbox for flash it is the local file system EX: c:/somefolder/somefile.flv for security reasons anything outside the development sandbox can not access local files without user interaction first IE a mouse click.

Comment: well my SWF, the HTML and the FLV are all in the same drive; shouldn't  that mean it's OK? Or is it because the FLV is in a path like ../../videos, i.e a different folder? Also why does it work on some PCs but not others? I can't undo the down-vote, it's "locked in" apparently unless you edit the post.

Comment: Again you are out of the sandbox if you are not running through the flash IDE. If you are out of the sandbox then all security measures take effect. If you want to access local content IE: stuff on the local hard drive then you should look into an air app. Browsers by default can not and will not allow access to content on the local machine.

Comment: Well it's working in most cases. The IDE is not involved. Hence my confusion because you're saying it won't work and in fact in many cases it is working.

Comment: You said it right here "On my PC it works fine but on a user's PC nothing is displayed. However if I host the exact same file-structure online and give them the URL, it works perfectly." You can not access the local file system without the user initiating the action. By hosting all the files you are no longer under the local file system which will cause it to be fine, aside from general domain security that is.